# JavaScript dependent variable values is not changing

Tags: javascript, variables, global-variables

I have 2 variables x and y. Variable y is related to x (y=x+2)

```
var x=2;
var y=x+10;

function increment(){
alert(x);
alert(y);
x++;
}
```

I am calling increment function to increment x and display values of x and y. So every time I call the function x is incremented but y value remains same.

Here is the output I get on subsequent clicks

2 12
3 12
4 12
5 12

If y is dependent on x why does the y value doesn't change.

Comment: Variables aren't recalculated automatically and have no "dependencies" once assigned. You want a function if you want a formula.

Comment: Please move the `var y=x+10;` line inside of your increment function.

Comment: Basically, you need to re-evaluate expression y=x+10 after calling increment function; only then y will get the change due to change in x value.

Answer (score 0):

You can define dependencies with getters

```
var values = {
    x: 2,
    get y() {
        return this.x + 10
    }
}

function increment(){
    alert(values.x);
    alert(values.y);
    values.x++;
}
```

This will recalculate y automatically when x was changed

Comment: And `y` would be readonly property, you will not be able to change y, but you can define a setter. Learn more [here](https://javascript.info/property-accessors)